# Weird iCloud Drive view

Tags: finder, icloud

How do I get to see all of the folders shown in the folder in [this question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58503/is-it-possible-to-backup-my-icloud-contents?noredirect=1&lq=1)
When I go to iCloud Drive all I see is:

[image]
(Parts of image containing personal information whited-out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the window icons, it appears you are using OS X Yosemite or later. The directories you see with icons (TextEdit) are equivalent to the Mountain Lion directories com~apple~Textedit. The additional directories belong to non-Apple software. What version of OS X/macOS are you using?

Comment: I am using Yosemite.